# Oracle encrypt/decrypt a clob

Tags: sql, oracle, encryption, clob

I  built a sha512 hash KEY based on a clob so I can easily check if the clob already exists.

It's based on a an INSERT trigger that is designed to call a function that will create the hash key.

I can successfully create my table, function and trigger and INSERT rows.

My next step is to store the CLOB encrypted during an INSERT and during a SELECT decrypt the CLOB during a SELECT for those who have the privilege.

I found some code on the internet that can crypt (see below) but where I'm stuck is being able to decrypt the clob. I suspect this should be possible but I can't find any examples of how to accomplish this task.

Secondly, I see a key in the code, which means anyone with DBA privileges can look at the source and see the key, which I don't want.

Would the best approach to avoid that situation be turning the code into a package and encrypting the package so the key and encryption method is unknown?

I suspect after this project some sensitive strings and BLOB will have to undergo the same undertakings so I was hoping for a very flexible solution to cover these situations or something with very minimal changes as I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Lastly, please let me know if there is a better encrypt method  then the one I found. As I'm not tied to any method as of yet.

Any help and expertise would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance to all who answer. I'm testing on livesql for anyone who wants to emulate my environment.

Below is a simple test CASE. Apologies for the locquatious write up.

```
CREATE table t(
seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
c CLOB,
hash VARCHAR2(1000)
);

  
 CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION HASH_SHA512 (
    psINPUT IN VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    rHash RAW (512);
    BEGIN
    rHash := DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH (TO_CLOB (psINPUT), 
dbms_crypto.HASH_SH512);
    RETURN (LOWER (RAWTOHEX (rHash)));
    END HASH_SHA512;
   

create or replace
    trigger trg
    before insert on  t
   for each row
    begin
    :new.hash := HASH_SHA512(:new.c);
    end;
  

 insert into t (c) values (
      rpad('z',32000,'z')
  );

SELECT DBMS_LOB.getLength(c) from t;

select hash from t;


-- looking for a decrypt function for this code.


create or replace function clob_encrypt(ac_input IN CLOB) return blob is 
  lb_variable BLOB; 
  inverse_type PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_DES + 
                                 DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC + 
                                 DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5; 
  inverse_key RAW(32) := UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw( '1220248819'); 
begin 
 
 dbms_lob.createtemporary(lb_variable, true);
 
 DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT( 
                 dst => lb_variable, 
                 src => ac_input, 
                 typ => inverse_type,--dbms_crypto.des_cbc_pkcs5, 
                 key => inverse_key 
                 ); 

   return lb_variable; 
end clob_encrypt;

select clob_encrypt('test') from dual;

CLOB_ENCRYPT('TEST')   
DEBD62BE84FC22A
```

Comment: If `DBMS_CRYPTO` has `ENCRYPT` function, then it should (reasonably) have [`DECRYPT`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_CRYPTO.html#GUID-7A041A3D-439B-4F7C-9FB9-8BC93E6DCC6A) function.

Comment: use encrypt and decrypt and include everything in a package. then use `wrap` to encrypt the code.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle's built-in solution to this problem is not encryption, but access control using Database Vault or Virtual Private Database to prevent the DBA or other users from seeing the data, respectively, and Transparent Data Encryption to encrypt the data at rest (OS/file-level encryption). This not only prevents the DBA from seeing the data, but from altering it or deleting it as well.

If you want to encrypt the data values anyway, then all encryption/decryption and key management should be handled *externally* from the database where the DBA won't have access to the encryption keys. How that works will depend on your application design and choice of programming language(s). Be aware that building a robust encryption and key management architecture is *not* a trivial exercise...

Also be aware that wrapping PL/SQL source code is only *obfuscation* of the code and not encryption. It can be *easily* reversed using any number of existing web sites or internal stored procedures. A true DBA would also have the `execute any procedure` privilege or be able to grant themselves explicit permission to execute any decryption function and not even have to care what the key was (only Database Vault could prevent this).

Transmitting the key to the function as an input instead of embedding it directly in the code would also be problematic, as the DBA can see your SQL in any number of ways. When transmitted via SQL query the key could also be exposed in ADDM reports, database trace files, or the audit trail.

There is *no* secure way to handle the encryption as you're describing with PL/SQL that also protects the data from the DBA.

Comment: @pmdba: What do you mean with: "...and not even have to care what the key was.. " ?

Comment: @Robbi If (as described) the key is embedded in the function _in_ the database then the DBA - or anyone else able to execute the function - can simply run it and not need to know what the key is. That's _by design_. Encrypting data with keys located _in_ the DB doesn't provide any security at all from users like a DBA with elevated privileges because they will _always_ be able to execute the functions unless Database Vault is deployed to limit them. The only other secure way to go is to put the keys and the encryption function in the app where the DBA can't access them.

Comment: Note: placing only the keys outside the database wouldn't help, as the key would have to be transmitted _to_ the function as part of a SQL statement, which the DBA then would be able to read and obtain the key from.

Comment: ok, put the key inside the encrypt function is not too smart. As you pointed out, the best thing would be to implement the encryption function with a native language and then store the result in DB using a driver (like ODBC). Did I get it right?

Comment: Yep, or deploy Database Vault. The advantage of using DB Vault is that it can be deployed without having to modify application code at all, without impacting performance, or the ability of _authorized_ users to search the data using SQL. Encrypting the data values (whether in the app or the DB) introduces processing overhead and makes direct searches of the encrypted data with SQL impossible. I would only do it on columns in rows that will only be processed individually, never in bulk.