# Oracle calling a package to decrypt a string

Tags: sql, oracle, encryption, plsql, package

I'm trying to implement encryption and decryption for strings as a lead into a larger POC where I will have to encrypt and decrypt CLOBS.

I'm well aware of the pitfalls of trying to play around with passwords. My intention is to start small with a string first then see how this could be implemented for CLOBS.

I know there are obvious issues like keeping the key in plain sight and there methods such as wallets to hide keys… but I only looking to get a simple test CASE working first with a string and then trying to implement it for a CLOB.

Secondly, once this process is working could it be easily retrofitted to encrypt and decrypt clobs, which is what I'm really looking into? I was hoping to use as much as the same code as possible with minimal amount of changes so I don't have to reinvent the wheel for different object types.

My test CASE is below and is failing on the last step and would appreciate some help getting it too work. I'm testing with livesql in CASE anyone wants to emulate my environment.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  id           NUMBER,
  username     VARCHAR2(30),
  cardnumber   NUMBER,
  password     VARCHAR2(200),
  CONSTRAINT customer_pk PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

create sequence customer_seq;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE encrypt_decrypt
AS
    FUNCTION encrypt (p_plainText VARCHAR2) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC;
    FUNCTION decrypt (p_encryptedText RAW) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY encrypt_decrypt
AS
    encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_DES
                                    + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                                    + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

    encryption_key     RAW (32) := UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw('HIDEANDSEEKINFO321');


    FUNCTION encrypt (p_plainText VARCHAR2) RETURN RAW DETERMINISTIC
    IS
        encrypted_raw      RAW (2000);
    BEGIN
        encrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
        (
            src => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW (p_plainText),
            typ => encryption_type,
            key => encryption_key
        );

        RETURN encrypted_raw;

    END encrypt;

    FUNCTION decrypt (p_encryptedText RAW) RETURN VARCHAR2 DETERMINISTIC
    IS
        decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);
    BEGIN
        decrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
        (
            src => p_encryptedText,
            typ => encryption_type,
            key => encryption_key
        );

        RETURN (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2 (decrypted_raw));

     END decrypt;

END;
/

insert into customer(id,username,cardnumber,password) values (customer_seq.nextval,'Fredrik',32435683, encrypt_decrypt.encrypt('kI32432J'));

-- Problem is here

select id,username,cardnumber,password,encrypt_decrypt(password) decrypted password from customer;
```

Comment: maybe it is just the space in your column name "decrypted password", try "decryptedpassword" instead

Comment: Just out of curiousity - why would you want to encrypt a complete CLOB ? That is going to be a real performance hit. Access to the raw data could be handled by application logic and if data needs to be hidden from users that have access to the database (for example for compliance reasons), then there are solutions available by Oracle like database vault

Comment: There is also [built-encryption for CLOBS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adlob/using-oracle-LOBs-storage.html#GUID-36592CEE-0C08-46A4-8218-D6CB1EB9EA12) - if you have the Oracle Advanced Security Option.

Comment: As pointed out in your original question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69120535/oracle-encrypt-decrypt-a-clob) this exercise - even if it works - provides _no actual security_ if your goal is to protect the data values from users with elevated privileges like the DBA. All it does is introduce processing overhead (possibly a LOT of it), make SQL searches of the data impossible, and introduce all new headaches of key management (like passwords, keys need to be changed periodically) and protection into your architecture. This path will _not_ get you where you want to go.

Comment: Transmitting the key to the function instead of embedding it in the code would also be problematic, as the DBA can see your SQL in any number of ways. When transmitted via SQL query the key could also be exposed in ADDM reports, database trace files, or the audit trail.

Comment: @Koen Lostrie I agree with you 110% that this should be handled by an application but we were asked to provide a POC before any real work was done. So that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Alex Poole no we aren't licensed for that option. Hopefully upper management will agree to move forward with that suggestion. I was asked to put together a POC and that's what I'm trying to do. Btw. I fixed the issue with the decryption of the string. Thanks for responding

Comment: @MarEll thanks I fixed the issue. Here is the solution.    Select id,username,cardnumber,password,encrypt_decrypt.decrypt(password) decryptedpassword
from customer;

Comment: @Pugzly How is it a legitimate POC if it can't meet the basic requirements you stated in your original question; that it is literally impossible to overcome the "obvious issues" you mentioned using nothing but PL/SQL code. I don't know the politics of your working environment, but IMHO you should report that to management as part of your evaluation of their request. Better that than to give them any false sense of security with this approach.

Comment: Keep in mind that the results of a POC may very well be *this concept in NOT viable*. Perhaps it should be here.  Either way I would not start with a string but a clob. The issues may turn out to be very different.

Comment: @Belayer I'm trying to work on encrypt and decrypt a CLOB too. As pemba mentioned there are plenty things that need to be considered. I hope they can see the light at the end of the tunnel

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
Select id,username,cardnumber,password,encrypt_decrypt.decrypt(password) decryptedpassword
from customer;
```